# How is $T$ an isomorphism?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

Here is the question I am trying to answer the second part of it:\

Let $V$ be a vector space of all $n$ by $n$ matrices over the field $F,$ and let $B$ be a fixed $n$ by $n$ matrix. Let $T: V \to V$ be defined by $$T(A) := AB - BA$$ Is $T$ a linear map? Is it an isomorphism?

**My question is:**

I managed to prove that it is a linear map. But how to think if it is an isomorphism or no, I am guessing yes, could someone help me in this please?

Comment: Not an isomorphism in general. This depends heavily on the choice of $B$. For example, $T = 0$ if and only if $B=\lambda {\rm Id}_n$ for some $\lambda \in F$.

Comment: It is finite dimensional and has a non-trivial kernel.

Comment: @Ivo It's never an isomorphism; $\mathrm{Id}_n$ is always an elements of the kernel

Comment: @Ben Duh. Of course.

Comment: @CyclotomicField how did you know that it has a non-trivial kernel?

Comment: Kernel of $T$ consists of all matrices that commute with $B$.

Comment: Does that because the identity matrix commutes with all matrices@AdamZalcman ?

Comment: If you know about the trace, its range is a proper subspace of $V$, as everything in its range has trace $0$. Thus $T$ is also never surjective.

Comment: @Brain Not just the identity but any scalar multiple of the identity. You should prove that $\lambda I$ is a subspace for scalar $\lambda$ and identity matrix $I$. Then consider the quotient space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $B=0$ the maping $T$ equals the zero homomorphism which is  not an isomorphism. Otherwise $T(B)=0$ and $B\not=0$. Thus $T$ is not injective, implying that $T$ is  not an isomorphism also in this case.